# Eloquent Create Only Inserting Blank Fields

Tags: eloquent, slim

I have stripped my code down to the bare minimum and still the fields I want to enter are set blank by Eloquent. I have set all the necessary fields to fillable and can update the fields that are initially set as blank.

I am using the Slim framework with Eloquent.

Post:

```
$app->post('/register', function() use($app){
    $request = $app->request;

$username = $request->post('username');
//this if was for validation which I removed for testing
if(true){
    $app->user->where('username', 'B1401812')->update(['username'=> 'FRANK']);
    $app->user->create(array(
        'username' => 'bob',
        'password' => 'ptest'
    ));
}else{
    $app->render('auth/register.php', [
        'errors'=> $v->errors(),
        'request' => $request
    ]);

}
```

User Model:

```
class User extends Eloquent
{
protected $table = 'user_information';


protected $fillable = [
    'username',
    'password',
    'active',
    'banner_location',
    'profile_picture_location'
];
public function __construct()
{

}
...some other functions
```

I've tried suggested solutions like disabling the Mass Assignment protection with no luck.

Comment: Can you edit your question, adding your whole route function?

Comment: Sure thing, I've added in the rest.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how Slim utilizes Eloquent, but could you try the code below?

```
User::create(array(
        'username' => 'bob',
        'password' => 'ptest'
    ));
```

I'm not sure what the instance at `$app->user` is referring to.

Comment: Sorry, just to clarify $app->user is just a function which returns a new User, I don't think this is the issue as it does insert the row, just the username and password fields on that row as set as blank